# Populate tableview with external database values in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a tablecell to work with and I can populate it when I use a written array (like `values = [""]`) so I know it is working.

But I am using json with swiftyjson to get my info in my table, which is part of a right slideout page I made with mmdrawer. When I `println` the json output I get all the info I need, but it is not being taken to the table or other variables/arrays.

How do I make this code work?

```
import UIKit

class RightSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var songname = [String]()
    var menuImage = [String]()




    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getmusiclist()

    }

    func getmusiclist(){

        let search:NSString = "music" as NSString

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://xxxxxx/music-manager.php")
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

    // set data
    var dataString = "search=\(search)"
    let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

    // set content length
    //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let dataReply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

    var results = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataReply!, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

    var jsonOutput = JSON(data: dataReply!)
        println(jsonOutput)
        let musicListArray = jsonOutput.arrayValue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            for playlist in musicListArray
            {
                let trackname = playlist["track_name"].stringValue
                println("trackName: \(trackname)")
                self.songname.append(trackname)
            }
           /* dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                })*/
            })

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return songname.count;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MusicTableViewCell

        mycell.artistLabel?.text = songname[indexPath.row]


        return mycell

    }
}
```

Eventually I would also like to take the name, genre and streaming url and have avplayer play it - will that be something I can add to this code?

Comment: After self.songname.append(track name),  call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: i will give that a try and see if it is working

Comment: i am calling it like this /* dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                })*/  do i have to put it directly after songname.append

Comment: i am getting the same error, "cannot invoke  dispatch_async with argument list of type (dispatch_queue_t!, () -> _)"

Answer (score 0):

the problem with in the part that i forgot to add the uitableview outlet in the uiviewcontroller. I have added it and now the error is gone. I still have to figure out why i am not getting anything but it seems that i am nu getting the data from the jsonOutput.arrayvalue.